# Efficient way to swap property values in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, flip

Assume we have the following array of Objects (the real has 71000 elements, but 4 objects are enough to give you an idea):

```
[
    {
        source: "France"
        target: "Morocco"
        timeN: "2008"
        valueN: "252.35"
    },
    {
        source: "France"
        target: "Morocco"
        timeN: "2009"
        valueN: "424.12"
    },
    {
        source: "France"
        target: "Morocco"
        timeN: "2010"
        valueN: "152.24"
    },
    {
        source: "France"
        target: "Morocco"
        timeN: "2011"
        valueN: "-342.19"
    }
]
```

How can I efficiently swap `source` and `target` values on the last object, if `valueN` is negative? I would like to just multiply `valueN` with `-1` or call `Math.abs()` and then change also `source` to `"Morocco"` and `target` to `"France"`.

### Update

Although all answers are great and I have taken the clean one by @Nina Scholz. However, the one from @Emil S. Jørgensen is the most performant one, once tracking the execution time. I don't know why but it seems to be most performant if you do not convert it back to a `string`, the `valueN`.

Comment: Is the part about flipping the last object just an example in this case? More clearly stated, are you looking to apply this flipping methodology to any of the 71,000 objects in the array that have a negative `valueN` or do you always want to flip the final object (i.e. the object in `array[array.length - 1]`)?...

Comment: why only the last object? please add the wanted result of *flipping*.

Comment: You want the source and target to be switched with each other?

Comment: @WillemvanderVeen: Only if `valueN` is -ve I believe

Comment: @Florian when asking a question, please stick around for a couple of minutes, so you can clarify issues and questions that show up in the comment. Your post has already 5 answers, 2 deleted, but people trying to help you are still *guessing* what your desired outcome is. Voting to close as *unclear*.

Comment: @War10ck: I always want to filp the objects `source` and `target` if the value of the respective object is negative. So for all 71,000 objects any occurences.

Comment: @All: Sorry for the late reply it was late yesterday and didn't expect that much answeres that fast. Thank you! and Sorry again.                                   @Nina Sholz & WillemvanderVeen: Yes only the `source` and `target` of negative object `valueN` should be filpped.                                                 @Gerardo Furtado: I am Sorry again. Really Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Iterate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). [Check](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else). [Swap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). [Update](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Multiplication_assignment).

```js
var array = [{ source: "France", target: "Morocco", timeN: "2008", valueN: "252.35" }, { source: "France", target: "Morocco", timeN: "2009", valueN: "424.12" }, { source: "France", target: "Morocco", timeN: "2010", valueN: "152.24" }, { source: "France", target: "Morocco", timeN: "2011", valueN: "-342.19" }];

array.forEach(o => {
    if (o.valueN < 0) {
        [o.source, o.target] = [o.target, o.source];
        o.valueN *= -1;
    }
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: WOW!! Thank you very much for the fast reply and great solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Mapping the array with a call to [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) and [Math.abs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs) seems the simplest solution:

```js
var data = [{
    source: "France",
    target: "Morocco",
    timeN: "2008",
    valueN: "252.35"
  },
  {
    source: "France",
    target: "Morocco",
    timeN: "2009",
    valueN: "424.12"
  },
  {
    source: "France",
    target: "Morocco",
    timeN: "2010",
    valueN: "152.24"
  },
  {
    source: "France",
    target: "Morocco",
    timeN: "2011",
    valueN: "-342.19"
  }
];
//Fix data by remapping values
data.forEach(function (entry) {
    var floatingValue = parseFloat(entry.valueN);
    entry.valueN = Math.abs(floatingValue);
    if (floatingValue < 0) {
        //Flipping
        var temp = entry.source;
        entry.source = entry.target;
        entry.target = temp;
    }
});
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Does `map` actually clone the objects or will this modify the original array's objects?

Comment: This is partially correct. Note the part about also flipping the source and target countries if the condition valueN < 0 is true.

Comment: @ManuelOtto Objects are passed by reference, so this method changes the original arrays objects.

Comment: @War10ck I have changed my snippet accordingly.

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen Perfect! +1

Comment: You're mutating the objects inside `.map`. It's not a good practice. We usually assume that `map` will create another array and let the original one intact.

Comment: @Gabriel I changed it to `forEach`.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I have now 3 great solutions already that I can try with the big data set and find the most performant one in order to process that many rows. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

```
array.forEach(x=> {
  if(x.valueN < 0){
    [x.source, x.target] = [x.target, x.source] //swapping values between two var
    x.valueN *= -1;
  }
});
```

You can try the above code. Loop thru the array and if found negative values, swap the variable and negate the valueN

Comment: Ye thats a great solution. I think it's similar to @Nina Scholz ones. I didn't know It can be that easy to swap values between object properties by using this notation.

Comment: @Florian: It's known as `Destructuring Assignment Array Matching`.

Comment: @Florian: Just a suggestion,as a token of appreciation you can upvote answers if you find them helpful :)

Comment: Ah I know about destructing. However didn't know this trick. I understood now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that works:

```js
let arr = [
    {
        source: "France",
        target: "Morocco",
        timeN: "2008",
        valueN: "252.35"
    },
    {
        source: "France",
        target: "Morocco",
        timeN: "2009",
        valueN: "424.12"
    },
    {
        source: "France",
        target: "Morocco",
        timeN: "2010",
        valueN: "152.24"
    },
    {
        source: "France",
        target: "Morocco",
        timeN: "2011",
        valueN: "-342.19"
    }
]



for (let el of arr) {


 if(parseInt(el.valueN) > 0) {
   continue;
 }
  
  let source = el.source;
  let target = el.target;
  
  el.target = source;
  el.source = target;
  
  el.valueN = (el.valueN * -1).toString();
}

console.log(arr);
```

Hopefully you find this helpful. If you do not understand a specific part you can further ask me about it.

Comment: WOW also thank you very much! I really like the idea too. I will try which solution is faster for the large dataset. Yours or @Nina Scholz ones. Anyway thank you!